# Problemas con la instalación de node y el angular/cli en linux ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, angular4, angular-cli

No me funciona lo que he encontrado en internet por ahora ¿Alguien lo ha instalado funcionalmente?

1 - pagina  http://www.nodejs.org/es/download  y Linux Binaries (x86/x64)

2 - Por defecto en Ubuntu, el compresor/descompresor de archivos tar.gx (antes conocido como LZMA) no esta instalado. Luego necesitas instalar el paquete xz-utils (desarrollado por la distribución Slackware):

```
sudo apt-get install xz-utils
```

3 - Después puedes descomprimir cualquier archivo tar.gz con file-roller o bien mediante terminal:

```
sudo tar -Jxf archivo.tar.xz
```

4 - instalar angular-cli desde node:

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

5 - Crea la aplicacion:

```
cd <<dir trabajo>>
sudo ng new app
```

error =>no esta el comando ng

La version de ubuntu es    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Comment: que versión de ubunto manejas

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Comment: Yo no veo que hayas instalado node. El comando `tar` lo descomprime, pero no lo instala. Revisa las instrucciones del sitio donde bajaste tu programa y asegúrate que las sigues.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Luego de eso

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Eso es para instalar node, para instalar Angular/cli es:

```
sudo npm install -g angular-cli
```

Comment: Lo que he puesto te instala la ultima version, no la del repositorio de ubuntu

Comment: de todas maneras, no encuentro forma de instalarlo

Comment: el actual es 9.1.0 y el que te instala asi es el 4.2.6

Comment: si no me equivoco

Comment: creo que es ese el problema, necesitare bajar fuente supongo y compilarlo

Answer (score 1):

*El hecho de que no te de error al hacer `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`, es un indicador de que actualmente debes tener instalada una versión de `Nodejs`. Prueba desinstalarla via `$ sudo apt-get remove nodejs` antes de realizar los pasos que se detallan debajo*

---

Según la [documentación de `Nodejs`](https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation), los pasos para instalarlo usando el `Binary archive` son los siguientes:

1. Extraer los binarios del archivo e instalar:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /usr/lib/nodejs
   sudo tar -xJvf node-v6.5.0-linux-x64.tar.xz -C /usr/lib/nodejs 
   sudo mv /usr/lib/nodejs/node-v6.5.0-linux-x64 /usr/lib/nodejs/node-v6.5.0
   ```
2. Agregar la variable de entorno al final del archivo `~/.profile`

   ```
   # Nodejs
   export NODEJS_HOME=/usr/lib/nodejs/node-v6.5.0
   export PATH=$NODEJS_HOME/bin:$PATH
   ```
3. Actualizar el `profile`

   ```
   . ~/.profile
   ```
4. Verificar la instalación:

   ```
   $ node -v
   $ npm version
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías considerar el instalar [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) que es para gestionar distintas versiones de node en tu computador. Para instalar, prueba con:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.6/install.sh | bash
```

luego instalas la última versión de node con:

```
nvm install node
```

y finalmente instalas el paquete que necesites (ojo, que no es necesario sudo, ya que todo queda instalado en tu home `~/.nvm`)

```
npm install -g angular-cli
```

Comment: esa opcion :curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.6/install.sh | bash me dice que no tengo los repositorios

Comment: ¿que repositorios necesito para esto? curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.6/install.sh | bash Creo que funciona pero no tengo todos los repositorios

Comment: ¿Por que "crees" que no te funciona? Si no me dices o muestras lo que específicamente te sale, no te puedo ayudar. ¿Viste la página de nvm para ver como instalar?